# circle as polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $D$ be the interior of the circle of $x^2+y^2=2x$. Find $$\int \int _D \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dA$$

I have a solution to this but it is not clear. It just says in the polar coordinates, the circle is $r^2 =2r\cosθ ⇒ r =0$ and $2\cosθ$. How did they straight away know this?

I just tried to let $x-1=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ but it turns out to be so hard to integrate.

Comment: Do you know how to convert from Cartesian to polar in general?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=2x$? Are you sure?

Comment: yes I know how to convert in general. and yes, no typos

Comment: Oops, I misread. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle equation can be rewritten as:

$$(x-1)^2+y^2 = 1$$

Changing to polar one gets the circle must satisfy:

$$r^2-2r\cos\theta=0$$ That basically tells us the interior of the circle are the points with $r\in(0,2\cos\theta)$ for a given $\theta$, and the circle is centered in $(1,0)$ with radius $1$, so the integral is:

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}d\theta\int_0^{2\cos\theta}dr r^2$$

The $r^2$ comes from your integrand function (thich gives one $r$) and the $r$ from the Jacobian.

I let the integral to you.
Your doubt was how to know the circle was $r^2=2r\cos\theta$, right? I hope I made it clear, you just have to see that $x^2-2x=(x-1)^2-1$

EDITION: the second equations comes from the first one:

$$(x-1)^2+y^2 = 1$$

Changing to polar: $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. So the circle satisfies:

$$(r\cos\theta-1)^2+r^2\sin^2\theta=1$$
$$r^2\cos^2\theta-2r\cos\theta+1+r^2\sin^2\theta=1$$

The $1$ goes away, and $\sin^2+\cos^2 = 1$, so:
$$r^2-2r\cos\theta = 0$$

Comment: I still don't get it at all with how you came to the conclusion on the second expression

Comment: @snowman I edited the answer with further details about that.

Comment: oh ok, was there anything wrong with the way I tried to do it? because I have never seen this way of doing it... I have done many of these questions in the past and I have never done it the this way.

Comment: @snowman What you do is equivalent to translating the circle (and the function) to the left so the circle is centered at the origin. That should give the same result. What I did was just evaluate the function in the area in which we're integrating.

Comment: So which method is best to use at all time? If there isn't an answer to that, how would you know which method is best to use in a particular question?

Comment: @snowman There is indeed no answer. In mathematics the method is usually problem-dependent. From my point of view, what I did is more straightforward, as I'm just calculating the integral, of course a lot of times you solve integrals by doing changes of variables that are not simple isometries such as a translation-rotation. You just have to look in each case which is the best method. In this particular case the integrand is just $r$ in polar coordinates, so trying to evaluate the area of integration in those coordinates seemed to be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use Cavalieri's principle. With a bit of trigonometry, we have that the length of the arc in $D$ for which $x^2+y^2=d^2$, when $d\in[0,2]$, is given by $2d\arccos\frac{d}{2}$, hence:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{2} d^2\arccos\frac{d}{2} = 8\int_{0}^{1}u^2\arccos u\,du=\frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^3}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du$$
(in the last step we applied integration by parts) and it follows that:
$$ I = \frac{8}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^3\theta\,d\theta = \color{red}{\frac{16}{9}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In the following, I try to answer just this part of the question:
"How did they straightaway know this?"

In the usual definition of polar coordinates, as you know,
the relationship between the Cartesian coordinates of a point,
$(x,y)$, and the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ of the same point is

$$ x = r \cos \theta,$$
$$ y = r \sin \theta.$$

This means that if you have an equation that is satisfied 
by the Cartesian coordinates of a particular point, $(x,y)$,
you can simply replace $x$ by $r\cos\theta$ and replace
$y$ by $r \sin \theta$ in that equation, and you will have an
equation satisfied by the polar coordinates of that point.
This is true because in the descriptions of this point by
its coordinates, $x$ and $r\cos\theta$ are *the same number*,
likewise $y$ and $r \sin \theta$.

There is a particular curve in the plane, such that every point on
that curve satisfies the given equation,
$$x^2 + y^2 = 2x.$$

Replacing $x$ by $r\cos\theta$ and $y$ by $r \sin \theta$, we
get another equation that must be true for every point on that curve:
$$(r\cos\theta)^2 + (r\sin\theta)^2 = 2(r\cos\theta).$$

Since $\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$, the left side of this equation
reduces to $r^2$. That reduction happens so often in coordinate geometry
that most people who see $x^2 + y^2$ will immediately replace it by $r^2$.
So you don't see the equation above written out in full,
but instead simply write $r^2 = 2(r\cos\theta).$

One might well ask not just *how* "they" knew they could do this, but
also *why* it might have occurred to them to try it.
As with a lot of math problems, there are a couple of likely explanations:
(1) you tried a bunch of things and this is the one that worked
(and you threw out your notes on all the failed methods);
(2) you were just lucky this was the first thing you tried; or
(3) something in the problem reminded you of something you've seen before
that works out nicely when you do this change of coordinates.
By the time someone gets around to writing this in a textbook or class notes,
it's probably due to the last reason, but someone seeing this for the first
time only has the first two options.

I think you *can* legitimately construct a system of polar coordinates in which
$r \cos \theta = x - 1$ instead of the usual $x$, but it's not the "obvious"
coordinate conversion and apparently it didn't help much in this problem.

Comment: thank you for the effort. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer regarding  how $ x^2 + y^2 = 2 a x $ is a circle.

Substitute $ x = r \cos\theta , y = r \sin\theta,  $ you get

$ r =  2 a \cos\theta .$ It is a circle of diameter $2 a $ touching y-axis at the
origin as a tangent. It is easy to integrate it now. In this case $a=1.$